# How to renew an existing Schengen visa for a trip to the Netherlands after 2 months?

Tags: schengen, netherlands, schengen-visas

I have a Schengen visa that will expire in 13 days (26th January 2018). I plan to visit the Netherlands again in March. Is there a way to renew my existing visa for March?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: apply for a new visa in the consulate that is responsible for your place of residence (or, more likely these days, though the private-sector service provider that is contracted to process visa applications on behalf of that consulate).

Comment: Do I have through the complete process again? I mean submitting the form along with all the documentation and also the biometric process?

Comment: Yes, since there's no real way of renewing a Schengen visa, you'll actually just have to apply again along with all new documents.

Comment: @crayarikar but it's probably not necessary to resubmit biometrics.

Comment: @phoog Yes that's true, but this really depends on the consulate in which the application is made and the consulates in which previous Schengen visa applications were made.

Comment: @crayarikar The previous and the current application are going to be in the same consulate. Does that make things easier in any manner?